# Bind updates to directive's element within link rather than inline with <el someattr="{{val}}"></el>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm creating a tabset directive.

In order to update ARIA attributes, and make tab actuation possible for the ENTER button, move between with arrow buttons, and other accessibility black magic, as well as clean up the markup on the directive's template, I (think) I want to do some of the element's two way binding in the link function instead of putting those things inline on the element.

i.e., instead of `<li aria-selected={{active}}/>Text</li>`

I want to reproduce that binding in the link instead to give me more control programmatically and a cleaner `<li>` element in the template.

However, it seems that element.attr('key',value) doesn't do that automatically, but only on the initial state. Which more or less makes sense, since the two-way binding is based on the {{}} on the element.

Would I need to do a $watch? Or something else? Or is there a neater way to do it? Or is this just a bad idea completely due to the overhead of $watches or other reasons?

So on load, this works fine, but obviously, doesn't update with changes in values:

```javascript
element.attr({
    'role': 'tab',
    'aria-controls': scope.tab.id,
    'id': 'tabFor' + scope.tab.id,
    'class':'tab'
    'aria-selected': !!scope.tab.active,
    'tabindex': scope.tab.active ? 0 : -1,
    'class': scope.tab.active ? 'tab active' : 'tab'
});
```

I'd like to be able to update these programmatically within the link function,  to clean up the template and give me more flexibility with the details.

That way the template can be this:

```html
<li tab-tab ng-repeat = "tab in tabsetCtrl.tabs>
        <span>{{tab.heading}}</span>
</li>
```

Instead of this:

```html
<li tab-tab ng-repeat = "tab in tabsetCtrl.tabs" ng-click = "tabsetCtrl.select(tab)" aria-controls = "{{tab.id}}" aria-selected = "{{tab.active?'true':'false'}}" tabindex = "{{tab.active?'0':'-1'}}"  ng-class = "{'active': tab.active}">
        <span>{{tab.heading}}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: You need to $watch whatever it is that changes to update the value.

Comment: Amy, if you want to copy and paste my answer into a new one, I'll select it as answered. Thanks so much. I was somehow making it more difficult for myself.

Comment: No worries. Anyone could have told you that :).

Comment: :)

I'm working in Angular with John Papa structures, and Typescript. Not to mention trying to make things dynamically accessible in the best possible ways for AT users. My brain is a little (a lot) fried. 

Thank you, StackO. You're my friend.

Comment: I think it's important to remember how young angular was when John Papa wrote his style guide. There are a lot of things I don't agree with, such as putting the name of a directive in the name of the View that's used as the template. You can use a View in a lot of different ways, including with a directive, but putting the directive name in there discourages you from reusing the view (for instance there are some places where we use a View with a directive and also use it in an ng-include with a different [or no] controller or with a different directive altogether).

Comment: Can you point me to any articles about current perspectives on that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105038/discussion-between-maxrocket-and-amy-blankenship).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @amy-blankenship

I added the watch.

```
// on load, the initial values are applied 

element.attr({
            'role': 'tab',
            'aria-controls': scope.tab.id,
            'id': 'tabFor' + scope.tab.id,
            'aria-selected': !!scope.tab.active,
            'tabindex': scope.tab.active ? 0 : -1,
            'class': scope.tab.active ? 'tab active' : 'tab'
        });


// On change to the active tab, new values are applied.

        scope.$watch("tab.active",function(){
            element.attr({
                'aria-selected': !!scope.tab.active,
                'tabindex': scope.tab.active ? 0 : -1,
                'class': scope.tab.active ? 'tab active' : 'tab'
            });
        });
```

Which takes care of it.